# how to get a active gtk window in gtk3?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I have tried like:

```
gdk_screen_get_active_window(gdk_screen_get_default());
```

But it return gdk window, and that's not what I want .

---

The reason for need gtk is that I want to get the active window's location by:

```
gtk_widget_get_allocation
```

anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Can you define what active window means? is it the window in your application that currently has input focus (or maybe last had input focus)?

Comment: last had input focus in system

Comment: You can't get a GtkWindow for another apps window, if that's what you're trying... For a start, the app might not be built with Gtk so the functionality is just not there (and also, you have no business seeing or modifying the internals of another app). The fact that you can get any info on the other apps windows without special privileges is basically a design bug in the window system.

Comment: @jku there are legitimate reasons to have read-only access to the window system: task managers, window lists, screenshot tools, automation tools, accessibility programs. There's also some merit in being able to reposition/resize foreign top-level windows (desktop organization). The important thing, however, is that a GtkWindow is not a GdkWindow.

Comment: @cxl I don't think GDK has a way to get the size of an arbitrary GdkWindow. You may need to tunnel down to a window manager-specific API like Xlib or xcb for X11 for this. wnck might also work. Good luck.

Comment: ok , I'll try anothor API . thanks~

Comment: The point I was trying to make was that this stuff only works without special permissions because X sucks and window managers have decided to leak this information to apps. Obviously there are special cases that require this info but writing an app that blindly depends on gdk_screen_get_active_window() returning something useful In 2016 should only be done after careful consideration...

Comment: I'm design a Screen shot app, when the mouse move in the active window area , I need mark the window's border...

Answer (score 2):

**it's close the correct location**

win=gdk_screen_get_active_window(gdk_screen_get_default());

gdk_window_get_position (win,NULL,&title_h);

gdk_window_get_root_origin(win,&win_x,&win_y);

win_width=gdk_window_get_width (win);

win_height=gdk_window_get_height(win);

Answer (score 0):

This method is right.Maybe You can call `gdk_screen_get_default()` to get GdkScreen to find whether it is null or not.If It is not null,maybe the questions are like this:

[GTK+3.0 API of gdk-screen-get-active-window](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/GdkScreen.html#gdk-screen-get-active-window)

Because thie method in my system run successfully.

Comment: gdk_screen_get_default() return is not null

Comment: the "gtk_widget_get_allocation " need GtkWidget but " gdk_screen_get_active_window " return a GdkWindow

Comment: I can use "gdk_window_get_width" to get window width .but that's not the real width ~

Comment: @cxl Please answer jku's comment above.

Comment: the active window is not in my application ( my application just have one window~ ), it's in system